# Fine properties of linear map $\mathscr{A}(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)=(\alpha_{i_1},\cdots,\alpha_{i_n})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be vector space consisting of all $n\times n$ complex matrices. Let $i_1,\cdots, i_n$ be a permutation of $1,\cdots,n$, define linear transform $\mathscr{A} $ on $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ as follows:
> \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned} \mathscr{A}(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)=(\alpha_{i_1},\cdots,\alpha_{i_n}), \end{aligned}\end{equation*}
> where $\alpha_k$ is a $n$-dimensional column vector, $1\leq k\leq n$.
> (1)、 Find $n$ linearly independent eigenvector of  $\mathscr{A}$;
> (2)、 Suppose $i_1=2, i_2=3,i_3=4, i_4=n, i_5=n-1,\cdots, i_n=1$, show $\mathscr{A}$ is diagonalizable.

I find by intuition that $E=(e_{ij}), e_{ij}=1$ is an eigenector of $\mathscr{A}$ with eigenvalue $1$, and maybe all the eigenvalues of $\mathscr{A}$ is the roots of $1$, the solution of $\lambda^n=1$. But I do not to do next. Help. Thanks.

Comment: So basically, $\mathcal{A}$ just swtiches the columns of the matrix? Then $E_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $E_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, up to $E_n = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are all invariant under $\mathcal{A}$, i.e., eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 1$. Does that look right?

Comment: For the second part, I think the result actually holds for any permutation $i_1, \dots, i_n$. First, I consider a simpler problem. Let $P: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ be a linear transformation on $n$-dimensional vectors, given by $P(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (x_{i_1}, \dots, x_{i_n})$ (i.e., it switches the entries). Then $P$ is a permutation matrix. A permutation matrix is unitary, hence always diagonalizable. Let $x^{(1)}, \dots, x^{(n)} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $P$.

Comment: Continuing from the last comment: Now we return to our problem. Consider $x^{(1)}$ as a row. Then the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} x^{(1)} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ x^{(1)} \\ \vdots\\  0
 \end{pmatrix}, \dots$, $\begin{pmatrix}  0 \\ 0\\ \vdots\\ x^{(1)} \end{pmatrix}$ are $n$ independent eigenvectors of $\mathscr{A}$. Repeat this construction for $x^{(2)}, \dots, x^{(n)}$. In the end, you get $n^2$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: @nowhere You should post these comments as an answer.

Comment: @Digitallis I wasn't sure if they are correct. Anyway, the question no longer seems relevant to the user who asked it. Should I still post an answer?

Comment: @nowhere You can do whatever you like. I was just scrolling through old posts and saw your comments which seemed to answer the question. I just think its best if answers are posted as answers. In this way if someone stumbles on this question they don't have to look through the comments to find an answer.  Of course if you don't have the time it's not really an issue. Clearly as you said the question is most likely no longer relevant to the user who asked the question.